# Catching Spirits

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, magic

Is there a way in Pathfinder to catch a spirit or bind it with your PC? (hopefully for the benefit of the PC)

I am hoping it is possible to possess a scroll or magical charm or something as my character is not magical (Barbarian). If that's not possible then what type of magical character would I have to play in order to achieve this?

Comment: Have you talked with your DM about it? If so, what did s/he say? Do you have magic-oriented party members that might be able to help? If so, have you talked to them about it?

Comment: yea I will speak to myt group but was just wondering if there is such a thing..

Comment: Define "spirit." Many classes have some kind of supernatural helper (like the Summoner), but I'm  not sure exactly what you're targeting here.

Comment: Sounds like your DM is doing something with spirits that s/he has made up specifically for your setting/campaign; probably only s/he can answer this question, as the Pathfinder rules don't seem to have rules for "spirits".

Answer (score 3):

An alternative version of Ranger, the [Spirit Ranger](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/ranger/archetypes/paizo---ranger-archetypes/spirit-ranger), forms a bond with nature spirits to give him [augury](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/a/augury) and a bonus spell.  This could be tweaked by your DM for your barbarian perhaps.

A [Spirit Oni](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/outsiders/oni/oni-spirit-oni) can be worn as a mask offering a +2 to Perception (though it is an evil creature)

There is a [Spirit Planchette](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/r-z/spirit-planchette) that allows you to commune with spirits (though it is dangerous)

[Protective Spirit](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/p/protective-spirit), [Spirit Guide or Spirit Guide, Greater](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/3rd-party-spells/4-winds-fantasy-gaming---3rd-party-spells/spirit-guide) could be added to a magic item, and provides bonuses to skill checks.

Finally, there are a number of barbarian [Rage Powers](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/barbarian/rage-powers) that are spirit related for example [Spirit Totem, lesser](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/barbarian/rage-powers/paizo---rage-powers/spirit-totem-lesser-su) that gains you spirit allies.